# How to count key-value pairs in a json formatted column

Tags: json, sql-server

I have the following JSON formatted data in a column ('Data') that is to be queried:
Record 1:

```
{  
    "actions":[  
        {  
            "class":"Action",
            "entries":[  
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartTime",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560858977855,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"O",
                    "value":"\"2019-06-17T11:58:38.000Z\""
                },
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartedBy",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560858977855,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"C_R",
                    "value":"1019"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Record 2:

```
{  
    "actions":[  
        {  
            "class":"Action",
            "entries":[  
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartTime",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560863293329,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"O",
                    "value":null
                },
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StopTime",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"com.bma.common.dto.Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560863293329,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"O",
                    "value":"\"2019-06-18T13:08:42.000Z\""
                },
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartedBy",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560858977855,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e6"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"C_R",
                    "value":"1018"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now what I need to establish is whether there is a stop time for every start time, in order to determine whether there are still any ongoing actions. Note that the first record does not have an object with a StopTime key. There are also records without a StartTime key. And, see Record 2, objects with a StartTime key can have a null value. This also goes for objects with a StopTime key. I have concocted the following sql which is far from finished:

```
SELECT ca1.[value] AS StartTimeCol,
ca2.[value] AS StopTimeCol
FROM queriedTable qu
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(qu.Data, '$.actions')
WITH (
entries nvarchar(max) '$.entries' AS JSON
) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.entries)
WITH (
[key] nvarchar(100) '$.key',
[value] nvarchar(100) '$.value'
) ca1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.entries)
WITH (
[key] nvarchar(100) '$.key',
[value] nvarchar(100) '$.value'
) ca2
WHERE
ca1.[key] = 'StartTime' OR
ca2.[key] = 'StopTime'
```

Obviously I have come to counting StartTimes and StopTimes yet; what puzzles me is that the result gives me in the StartTimeCol and StopTimeCol columns values from other objects, like "1019" and "1018" although I explicitly state that only the keys StartTime and StopTime must be considered. How come? And how can I establish in one query whether the number of StopTimes is larger than or equal to the number of StartTimes?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, next approach may help:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE queriedTable (
   Data nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO queriedTable 
   (Data)
VALUES
    (N'{  
    "actions":[  
        {  
            "class":"Action",
            "entries":[  
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartTime",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560858977855,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"O",
                    "value":"\"2019-06-17T11:58:38.000Z\""
                },
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartedBy",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560858977855,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"C_R",
                    "value":"1019"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
   ),
   (N'{  
    "actions":[  
        {  
            "class":"Action",
            "entries":[  
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartTime",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560863293329,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"O",
                    "value":null
                },
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StopTime",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"com.bma.common.dto.Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560863293329,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e7"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"O",
                    "value":"\"2019-06-18T13:08:42.000Z\""
                },
                {  
                    "class":"Entry",
                    "id":null,
                    "key":"StartedBy",
                    "performance":{  
                        "class":"Performance",
                        "origin":null,
                        "originUuid":null,
                        "performanceDateTime":1560858977855,
                        "performerUuid":{  
                            "class":"java.util.UUID",
                            "UUID":"2647a005-a3a8-4362-8f2d-ddd188f500e6"
                        },
                        "registrationDateTime":null,
                        "userUuid":null
                    },
                    "type":"C_R",
                    "value":"1018"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT
   RANK() OVER (ORDER BY qu.Data) Rn,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY qu.Data) [Count],
   b.*
FROM queriedTable qu
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(qu.Data, '$.actions') WITH (
   Data nvarchar(max) '$.entries' AS JSON
) a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.Data)  WITH (
   [key] nvarchar(max) '$.key',
   [value] nvarchar(max) '$.value'
) b
WHERE b.[key] = 'StartTime' OR b.[key] = 'StopTime'
```

Output:

```
Rn  Count   key          value
1   1       StartTime   "2019-06-17T11:58:38.000Z"
2   2       StartTime   
2   2       StopTime    "2019-06-18T13:08:42.000Z"
```